# How to use java exoplayer in C++ Qt android project?

Tags: java, android, qt, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I have qt project with QMediaPlayer in it and I want to use java exoplayer instead of QMediaPlayer.

I trying to add google repository in adroid/build.gradle

```
...
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
}
...
```

and it causes this error:

> Could not find method google() for arguments [] on repository
>   container.

... because Qt uses very old version of gradle and I can't change this.

What can I do with this? Maybe there is a way to put exoplayer in *.so library or any other compiled library.